# How to calculate $||\vec u-\vec v+\vec w||$ using their inner product space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
<,> & \text{$\vec u$} & \text{$\vec v$} & \text{$\vec w$} \\
\hline
\vec u & 4 & 0 & 2 \\
\vec v & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\vec w & 2 & 3 & 7 \\
\end{array}
$$

I know that $||\vec u||=2, ||\vec v||=1, ||\vec w||=\sqrt 7$ by taking the square root of their inner product space, and that $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are orthogonal because $<\vec u,\vec v>=0$. What can I do next?

Comment: Compute $\lVert \vec{u} - \vec{v} + \vec{w}\rVert^2$ using the table of inner products you have. Then take the square root.

Comment: the square of norm  is like  $u^2+v^2+w^2-2u.v-2v.w+2u.w$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\| u - v  + w \|^2 = \langle u - v  + w, u - v  + w \rangle = \langle u, u \rangle + \langle u, -v \rangle + \langle u, w \rangle + \langle -v, u \rangle +\dots$$